# How to deploy a Wordpress website to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

Please give any useful tutorial to explain how to deploy a Wordpress website into Google cloud storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy a Wordpress website to Google Cloud Platform:

[Quick Start WordPress for Google App Engine](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/)